# Image not uploading in laravel through ajax

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am submitiing my form through ajax.

```
<form id="addProductForm" action="javascript:void(0)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="productId">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">   
         </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <button type="submit" id="submitAddProduct" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto ml-auto" style="margin-top:15px;">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the submit script

```
$('#submitAddProduct').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var image = $('#image').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/submitAddProduct',
        async:false,
        data:{
            'image' : image,
        },
        success:function(response) {
            $('#productId').val(response.msg);
        }
    });

});
```

In my controller,

```
public function submitAddProduct(Request $request){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'image' => ['required','image']
        ]);

        public function submitAddProduct(Request $request){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'image' => ['required','image']
        ]);

        // dd(request('image')->store('uploads','public'));

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();

        $id = Products::insertGetId($data);

        if($id){
            $arr = array('msg' => $id);
        }
        return Response()->json($arr);
    }

        $id = Products::insertGetId($data);

        if($id){
            $arr = array('msg' => $id);
        }
        return Response()->json($arr);
    }
```

image val is something like C://fakepath//name;
I want image to be uploaded to storage/uploads in my public folder.

But i am getting errors.
`422 Unprocessable Entity`

Please Help. Thank You

Comment: Fyi, `dd(...)` ends your script, use `dump(...)` if you want it to continue running

Comment: r u passing csrf token ?

Comment: sir this is GET request, i thought we dont need csrf for that, and also i know about dd, it should show the path, but it isnt showing anything

Comment: Please have a look, i have edited the question, i actually want it to be saved in uploads

Comment: Try and look at the request being sent in the network inspector tab. It should tell you that the actual image file isn't being sent.

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitAddProduct?name=asfs&min_order=13&units_id=1&selections_id=2&subcategories_id=1&description=scad&image=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5CfibreGlass.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: Sorry if url isnt visible, `&image=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5CfibreGlass.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

My current guess would be that your image gets stripped from the request, because it is bigger than upload_max_filesize and post_max_size allow. Can you try posting a very small (<100kB) image?

My rationale for this is that, if the file is too big, it gets stripped. If it is stripped, the validation rules fail, thus resulting in a 422.

Edit: I just noticed you're working with GET as an HTTP verb. Files can only be sent using POST (and PUT and PATCH, but let's leave those out for now).

Comment: Okay sir, i will try it with POST then

Comment: You will also not want to use `.val()`, but access the actual File object of that input. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET to upload files which does not make any sense.

1. change the route from get to post in the routes file.
2. Change the ajax code to send POST rather than GET.
3. include the CSRF token in the ajax request:

   - Using headers:

     1. Add the following html `meta` tag to head (if it does not exists already):
        `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`.
     2. Add the header to your ajax:

     ```
     $.ajaxSetup({
         headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         }
     });
     ```
   - Or simply, add the token as parameter in the request itself:

     ```
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         ...
         data:{
         '_token' : {{ csrf_token() }},
         ...
     },
     ```
4. That should do the trick!

Side note: try using named routes (easier to maintain), and I recommend using Axios.

> By default, the resources/js/bootstrap.js file includes the Axios HTTP library which will automatically send this for you - Laravel docs